# Post an image along with text in django restframework with flutter

Tags: android, django, flutter, django-rest-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

I am creating a b2b e-commerce mobile application. I am using flutter as frontend and django for backend. I am stuck while sending a post request to django server with flutter. The case is I have two types of user. They are seller and buyer. The seller has to post product in the app. Model field for product are title, description, price and image. I created post method in django rest framework and it worked while checking through postman. But I am having hard time sending image through flutter. I used image picker to get the image. I searched for many things but could not figure out what to do. I found articles and videos posting only image at a time but i want to send image along with other text field. How can i do so??

Help me find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

It is better that you upload your selected image with multipart and separate api, but if you want send image with other info , you must, first decrease quality of image until request time was decreased(don't receive timeout api), and also use base64 for this.

Key word for searching for more info, upload image with base64